# finding and setting new var from ansible_net_config

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to come up with a way to find a piece of text in a very long string.  I'm using the ios_facts module to grab a Cisco config.  I'm looking for the text below and want to set it as a new var.  The 'ip nbar protocol-pack' portion will never change but the value after that will vary from node to node.

{{ ansible_net_config }} =
o ip source-route\n!\n!\n**ip nbar protocol-pack bootflash:pp-adv-isr4000-169.1-34-47.0.0.pack** \n!\n!\n!\n!\nip nb

the value of ansible_net_config is much longer.  I trimmed it down for sanity sake.

This is what I want the var set to:
**ip nbar protocol-pack bootflash:pp-adv-isr4000-169.1-34-47.0.0.pack**

Here is the code I'm working with.  I don't know if I should keep trying regex_search or try json_query or something I'm not yet aware of.

```
---
- name: Cisco NBAR Test
  connection: ansible.netcommon.network_cli
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - name: collect facts
      cisco.ios.ios_facts:
        gather_subset:
        - config
    
    - name: set vars
      set_fact: config={{ ansible_net_config | regex_search('ip nbar protocol-pack') }}
      #set_fact: config={{ ansible_net_config | community.general.json_query('*') }}

    - name: show output
      debug:
        var: config
```

Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried and what error is it producing for you? I don't see any code in your question, nor any logs from the execution of your attempt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write   the regexp like this:

```
set_fact: config="{{ ansible_net_config | regex_search('.*ip nbar protocol-pack.*')  | trim }}"
```

---

```
- name: test
  hosts: localhost
  
  tasks:
    - name: set vars
      set_fact: config="o ip source-route\n!\n!\nip nbar protocol-pack bootflash:pp-adv-isr4000-169.1-34-47.0.0.pack \n!\n!\n!\n!\nip nb"
    - name: regex vars
      set_fact: result="{{ config | regex_search('.*ip nbar protocol-pack.*') | trim }}"
    - name: show
      debug:
        var: result
```

---

result:

```
TASK [show] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "result": "ip nbar protocol-pack bootflash:pp-adv-isr4000-169.1-34-47.0.0.pack"
}
```